# Adequacy of question for ServerFault

Tags: discussion

Is [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/818800/cannot-mount-synology-nfs-from-debian-terminal) adequated to be posted on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) and if not, which subside should be posted in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this about your home NAS? In that case, it would be [off-topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)  and it should be posted either on [SU](http://superuser.com) or [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com). If this is for your work network (not home office!), it would be OK here.

Comment: The problem is around work network.